# Angular2 reloading config files from a JSON file when page refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a json file that consists of API Endpoints which is loaded during initialization of the app using APP_INITIALIZER from the app.module.

Then I have a function that reads the endpoint value from the JSON file via http.get function. This function is executed during app initialization.

```
export function initConfig(config: AppSettings){
 return () => config.load() 
}

public load() {
    this._http.get('/assets/ngConfig.json').map((res: any) => res.json()).subscribe((response) => { this.config = response });
}
```

The values from the json files loaded successfully during initial load.

The issue is whenever I hit browser's refresh button the config/endpoints is set to NULL thus gives me error.

What approach should I do for this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code. Your question doesn't provide any information that would enable others to provide support.

Comment: added the code that is invoked during app initialization. it is just a simple function that assigns the response to an object.